# jQuery Animation logo fade in fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently stuck here, I want to realize the same effect as [this website](http://www.yamashitasekkei.co.jp/). But I don't know exactly how to do it. Would anybody be kind enough to show me the code to do it?

Basically, this site shows a logo for a couple of seconds in the beginning and then fades out to a div area. I want to make my own version to show my own logo and then fade into the content in a div area that I want to show to the others. Both the logo show out and the div must be on the same web page.

Please help.

Comment: 1) you need to link to the site with the thing that you want, and 2) you need to give it a shot and share your work with us with a clear question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "I want to make my own version" --> proceed. Then come back to us when your code isn't working.

Comment: I'll give you a hint, and after you come back and show what you've tried, I'll see where you may need help. The following terms will help you achieve the desired effect: `setInterval(), clearInterval(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(),` and `absolute positioning`. These are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require jQuery at all, it can be done with CSS easily.

Here's a demonstration:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Valid HTML5 documents require title tags </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #logo {
            position: fixed;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            pointer-events: none;
            cursor: default;

            transition: opacity 2.5s ease 5s, height 3s ease 7.5s;
            /*                 __^__    __^__      __^__    __^__
                                [1]      [2]        [3]      [4]

                [1] Time opacity takes to transition from 1 to 0;
                [2] Time opacity waits until it starts transitioning
                [3] Time height takes to transition from 100% to 0;
                [4] Time height waits until it starts transitioning (>= [1] + [2]);
            */
        }
        .preload #logo {
            opacity: 1;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="preload" onload="document.body.className='';">
    <div id="logo"> YOUR LOGO HERE </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1> wow, a title </h1>
        <p> yay, content </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, how does it work?

`<body>` has the `preload` class. As soon as it loads (`onload` event), that class is removed.

While `<body>` has the `preload` class, `div#logo` will have `opacity: 1` and `height: 100%`.

As soon as `<body>` loses the `preload` class, `div#logo` will have both `opacity` and `height` set to 0. But the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property stops that change from being immediate.

`opacity` waits 5 seconds (delay) to start the transition.

`opacity` takes 2.5 seconds to fully transition from 1 to 0.

`height` waits 7.5 seconds (opacity's 5s + 2.5s) to start the transition.

`height` takes 3 seconds to fully transition from 100% to 0.

You get the desired effect with barely any JavaScript and no need for an external framework.

Comment: Thx a lot, ur answer rosolved most part of my question. Really thx a lot. But I still got some questions for u, if u dont mind plz help me here, how to make a delay effection on " Your logo here" when it appears, I mean let its appearence fade in.